# Разбор логов с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, сопоставление-с-образцом

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, в консоли мне выводит такое:

```
742   model 1 category 1   2218240  Kyiv  1447162980 src_ 2015-11-10 15 43 00   2200001  Darnytsya
```

Мне нужно только оставить:

```
742 Kyiv 2015-11-10 15:43:00 Darnytsya
```

Кто может помочь?
Как можна дописать этот код?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9_-]+");  
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);  
    while(m.find()){System.out.print(data.substring(m.start(), m.end())+" ")}
```

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться обычным `split(" ")`, а потом поклеить нужные части?

Answer (score 1):

Если брать строку, которая есть, то код будет такой

```
String string = "742   model 1 category 1   2218240  Kyiv  1447162980 src_ 2015-11-10 15 43 00   2200001  Darnytsya";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+.+?\\d{6}\\s+(\\w+).+?src_\\s(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2})\\s+\\d+\\s+(\\w+)").matcher(string);
if (matcher.find())
{
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3).replace(' ', ':'));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

**OUT:**

```
742

Kyiv

2015-11-10:15:43:00

Darnytsya
```

**P.S.** по одной строке очень сложно написать правильную регулярку, но данная регулярка для данной строки подходит

Answer (score 0):

Воспользовавшись методом `String.split`, разбить вывод консоли `data` на отдельные поля.

```
String[] fields = data.split("\\s+");
System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s:%s:%s %s", fields[0], fields[6], fields[9], fields[10], fields[11], fields[12], fields[14]);
```

Comment: Это бы подошло, если б каждный раз строка не менялась. А причина в том, что эта строка каждный раз может быть другая.  `742   model 1 category 1   2218240  Kyiv  1447162980 src_ 2015-11-10 15 43 00   2200001  Darnytsya`.    В следующий раз может быть: `72   model 1 category 1   2218240  Dnipropetrovsk  1447162980 src_ 2015-11-10 15 43 00   2200001  Kyiv`

Comment: Какие есть ещё варианты? Что в них другое? В примерах никаких принципиальных различий не вижу. Что там, что сям 15 полей, разделённых пробелами

Comment: `742   1  1   2218240  Truskavets  1447162980 src_ 2015-11-10 15 43 00   2200001  Darnytsya  1447187400 src_ 2015-11-10 22 30 00 types title Seating first class letter u04211 places 156 title Seating second class letter u04212 places 349`...а может быть такая строка `050   0  0   2218240  Truskavets  1447179000 src_ 2015-11-10 20 10 00   2200001  Kyiv-Pasazhyrsky  1447218900 src_ 2015-11-11 07 15 00 types title Suite first-class sleeper letter  places 3 title Coupe coach with compartments letter u places 21 title Berth third-class sleeper letter u041f places 33 `..и я себе ломаю говову

Comment: Извините, просто неправильно обьяснил проблему темы:(

Comment: Тогда см. ответ Andrew Bystrov. Может `^` добавить в начало выражения

Comment: А можете пожалуста обьяснить что это изменит? Что бы я понимал)

Comment: ^ означает начало проверяемой строки (если само в начале поставлено). Вдруг попадётся строчка, которая где-то в середине совпадает с выражением. Но Вам-то нужны только такие, которые начинаются этим выражением?